# Merge 2 sorted linked list wrong answer

Tags: java, merge, linked-list

So I am doing the hackerrank problem on merging two sorted linked list. This is what I have

```
    // Complete the mergeLists function below.

    /*
     * For your reference:
     *
     * SinglyLinkedListNode {
     *     int data;
     *     SinglyLinkedListNode next;
     * }
     *
     */
    static SinglyLinkedListNode mergeLists(SinglyLinkedListNode head1, SinglyLinkedListNode head2) {

        SinglyLinkedListNode curr1 = head1;
        SinglyLinkedListNode curr2 = head2;
        SinglyLinkedListNode head = new SinglyLinkedListNode(0);
        SinglyLinkedListNode curr = head;



        while(curr1.next != null && curr2.next != null){

            if(curr1.data < curr2.data ){

               curr.next = curr1;
               curr = curr.next;
               curr1 = curr1.next;


            }

            else{

                curr.next = curr2;
                curr=curr.next;
                curr2 = curr2.next;
            }

        }

        if (curr1.next == null ){
            curr.next = curr2;
        }


        head = head.next;
        return head;


    }

    private static final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
```

however this is the output I am getting

1 2 3 4
as opposed to

1 2 3 3 4

The test case is

linked list 1 : 1,2,3
linked list 2: 3,4

Comment: What happens when the loop ends because `curr2.next == null` but `curr1.next` is not `null`?

Comment: @jeppe yes same error

Comment: @lurker I accidently removed it here but its the same thing for when curr1.next is null. I put it back in and still same error

Comment: It is because the condition in the while loop. You are not considering the last element in the first linked list, as its next is null. Your logic does not look right

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `if` clause for the case when both elements are equal to each other.

```
        else if (curr1.data > curr2.data) {
            curr.next = curr2;
            curr = curr.next;
            curr2 = curr2.next;
        } else {
            // assign node from 2nd list
            curr.next = curr2;

            // increment 2nd list
            curr2 = curr2.next;
            curr = curr.next;

            // asign node from 1st list
            curr.next = curr1;

            // increment 1st list
            curr1 = curr1.next;
            curr = curr.next;
        }
```

Comment: still coming up as the same answer I have above, as 1,2,3,4 and not 1,2,3,3,4

Comment: can you put System.out.println to debug

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the head to the remaining list when one of them is complete. This happens in cases where both the lists are of different size:

Replace

```
if (curr1.next == null ){
    curr.next = curr2;
}
```

with

```
if (curr1.next == null ){
    curr.next = curr2;
} else if (curr2.next == null ){
    curr.next = curr1;
}
```